# what's difference between classLoader.getResource(".") with classLoader.getResource("")?

Tags: java, path

```
ClassLoader classLoader = UploadFileService.class.getClassLoader();
String path1=classLoader.getResource(".").getPath(); 
String path2=classLoader.getResource("").getPath();
```

in tomcat application, the paths are not same. but in local example, they are some.

what's difference between classLoader.getResource(".") with classLoader.getResource("")?

as titled.

Comment: Concerning what exactly?

Comment: No differences I guess. They both mean current path.

Comment: The difference is a `.` ;-)